# Dictionaries in Array in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm new to Swift and I have a problem. 
I'm trying to create an array of dictionaries in my app from table cells results and make a POST. It must be like this:

```
{"basket":"[{product_id: 6, quantity: 1}, {product_id: 7, quantity: 1}]"}
```

So there is a part of my code:

```
var basketNew: [AnyObject] = []

func tableView(bla-bla){
   var basket = ["product_id":"\(myVal)", "quantity":"\(myVal)"]
   self.basketNew.append(basket)
}
```

After that I put it into new dictionary:

```
var params = ["basket": self.basketNew] as Dictionary
```

And get a result from server:

```
{"basket":"[{product_id: 6}, {quantity: 1}, {product_id: 7}, {quantity: 1}]"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my POST request:

```
var request = HTTPTask()
    request.POST(self.domainNew, parameters: params, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
        if let data = response.responseObject as? NSData {
            var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("response: \(strData)")
            var err: NSError?
            var result = 0
            var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as NSDictionary
println("Very Good")
            }
            }, failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
                println("Very Bad")

        })
```

I'm using framework SwiftHTTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
var basketNew: [[String: Int]] = []

func tableView(bla-bla){
    basketNew.append(["product_id": 6, "quantity": 1])
}

var params = ["basket": basketNew]
```

Update:

[image: screenshot in playground]

Update 2:

[image: dictionary array]

Comment: The same result =\ "product_id" and "quantity" are not in the same dictionary.

Comment: how do you send `params` to the server? maybe there's a problem sending it. i've added a screenshot of my code in playground — it looks how it should :)

Comment: And result on server still = `{"basket":[{"product_id":"6"},{"quantity":"1"},{"product_id":"7"},{"quantity":"3"}]}`

Comment: There is full code of params:         `var params = [`
            `"test": "1",`
            `"hash": "1",`
            `"order_info": [
                "user_id": "\(self.userId)",
                "name": "\(self.nameField.text)",
                "phone": "\(self.phoneField.text)",
                "address": "\(self.adressField.text)",
                "pay_type": "\(self.chkIndex)",
            ],
            "basket": self.basketNew
        ] as Dictionary`

Comment: I have the same result in console. But not on server.

Comment: could you show us your code, how you send the post request?

Comment: Code of POST added to question

Comment: The problem was on server